# T-SQL stored procedures

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table `Users` with the following columns:

```
  Userid   Username    Password
     1     Username1   Password1
     2     Username2   Password2
     3     Username3   Password3
```

There is another table, `MappingRoles`:

```
 Userid   RoleId
     1       1 (FinanceUser)
     1       2 (Agent)
     1       3 (Client)
```

I want to write a stored procedure which should return two columns

```
IsValidUser
Roles -- of the user
```

This is my attempt:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  getRoles
    @Username varchar(50), 
    @Password varchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
    Select * from Users as x inner join MappingRoles as y 
    on x.Userid=y.Userid 
    where x.Userid=(Select Userid from Users 
      where UserName='Username1' and Password='Password1');
END
GO
```

I am expecting optimization in this query to provide 2 return values:

- `IsUserAuthenticated` - (the inner `Select` from `Users`)
- If it's present then all the values.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marc this is just sample fields. Its encrypted in actual table TripleDES.

Comment: As I understand your question, a typical result would be a row like `( 1, 'Agent, Client' )`, correct?  Shouldn't that be `select RoleId` in your return values example?

Comment: Hi HABO, Currently this sp will return 3 rows -

Comment: Hi HABO, Currently this sp will return 3 rows showing that Userid 1 has 3 roles as per mapping table. Assuming that the user is present.But there may be problem in query - I want to optimize by putting a flag in this query first to check if user exists and if exists then some out parameter (true or false) and return all roles .Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a simpler join, drop the sub query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  getRoles
    @Username varchar(50), 
    @Password varchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
    Select 
        * 
    from Users as us 
    inner join MappingRoles mr 
    on us.Userid=mr.Userid 
    where us.UserName=@username and us.Password=@password);
END
GO
```

Comment: OP possibly intended `where us.UserName=@Username and us.Password=@Password`.